# grep the log file after running script and need to show the log file

Tags: linux, grep

I need to run the script grep the logfile and then show the log file. I have tried the following command
sh abc.sh | grep "Log File: "| sed -e s/'Log File (.*)$')

I got an error as: sed expression #1 unterminated s' command

Comment: `sed -e s/'Log File (.*)$'` is invalid. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: Perhaps you meant: `sed -e 's/Logfile: //'`

Comment: But `grep | sed` is an anti-pattern.  Try `sh abc.sh | sed -n -e '/Log File:/s///p'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your `sed` command is invalid.  It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do with that invalid `sed`, but I think you're looking for:

```
sh abc.sh | sed -n -e '/Log File:/s///p'
```

This will suppress all output except those lines which match the regex `Log File:`, and the text `Log File:` will be replaced with the empty string.  (`s///p` will use the previous pattern for the match, and replace the first occurrence of that pattern with the empty string.  The `p` flag causes the line to be printed.)